# unable to install package: libtbb2-dev : Conflicts: libtbb-dev but 2021.5.0-7ubuntu2 is to be installed

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'itascasoftware' instead of './itascasoftware_700.146.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libtbb2-dev : Conflicts: libtbb-dev but 2021.5.0-7ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: It seems your package management may have preexisting problems. Your system should be up-to-date and your package manager should be error free before attempting to install new software. Please edit your question and add the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. This will let us help you solve any problems you might have with sources or package management. Please copy/paste the whole output of each command and use [code fences](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/20164). Tag me @nmath in a comment when complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dpkg 'force' to install the package and ignore unmet dependencies:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i ./itascasoftware_700.146.deb
```

It will unpack the package and list the missing dependencies. You will see something like:

```
dpkg: itascasoftware: dependency problems, but configuring anyway as you requested:
 itascasoftware depends on libmkl-dev (>= 2020.0.166-1); however:
  Package libmkl-dev is not installed.
 itascasoftware depends on libncurses5-dev; however:
  Package libncurses5-dev is not installed.
 itascasoftware depends on libncursesw5-dev; however:
  Package libncursesw5-dev is not installed.
 itascasoftware depends on libcurl4-gnutls-dev; however:
  Package libcurl4-gnutls-dev is not installed.
 itascasoftware depends on libzmq3-dev; however:
  Package libzmq3-dev is not installed.
 itascasoftware depends on ttf-mscorefonts-installer; however:
  Package ttf-mscorefonts-installer is not installed.
```

You can then manually use apt to install the listed missing dependencies